# Realm dotnet v0.75.0 - error : Failed to resolve "System.String System.String::Format(System.IFormatProvider,System.String,System.Object)"

Tags: .net, realm

I am trying to use Realm dotnet v0.75.0. However when I try to build it I get the following error in my Xamarin iOS project. This occurs just by installing the Realm Nuget package, I am not even referencing the library in my code yet. I am using PCLs

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(673,3): error : Failed to resolve "System.String System.String::Format(System.IFormatProvider,System.String,System.Object)" reference from "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"
```

Any ideas? Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: This seems like a bug. Would you mind opening an issue for it on GitHub? https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues

Answer (score 0):

Now fixed in the v0.76.0 release.